# GWT 2.5 maven plugin throws errors for i18n generation in Linux

Tags: gwt

GWT 2.5 maven plugin throws errors for i18n generation in Linux but works perfect in Windows.
I tried to run with -X option but did not find any useful error descriptions in logs.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/cms</webappDirectory>
                <hostedWebapp>target/${project.artifactId}</hostedWebapp>
                <i18nMessagesBundles>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>package.module1.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>package.module2.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                    <i18nMessagesBundle>package.module3.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
                </i18nMessagesBundles>

                <modules>
                    <module>package.module1.Module1</module>
                    <module>package.module2.Module2</module>
                    <module>package.module3.Module3</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

The problem stack trace is the following

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:i18n (default) on project application: Command [[
>   /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath [CLASSPATH] com.google.gwt.i18n.tools.I18NSync -out /home/alex/development/camomile-cms/svn/application/target/generated-sources/gwt -createMessages com.comomile.cms.ria.fs.client.Messages
>   ]] failed with status 1
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException: Command [[
>   /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath [CLASSPATH] com.google.gwt.i18n.tools.I18NSync -out /home/alex/development/comomile/svn/application/target/generated-sources/gwt -createMessages com.comomile.cms.ria.fs.client.Messages
>   ]] failed with status 1
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo$JavaCommand.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:485)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.I18NMojo.doExecute(I18NMojo.java:133)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:172)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       ... 19 more
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
>   [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :application
>   alex@alex-pc:~/development/comomile/svn$

Comment: You say "... throws errors ...". How about including these errors in your question so that people may help you?

Comment: Ok, i will attach them but they were not meaningful as i wrote here...

Comment: They may not be meaningful to you but they will hopefully mean something to someone else that will hence be able to help you.

Comment: Looks like i need to debug the plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after debugging.

Solution is **to create property files with messages using capitalized first letter**: for example "Messages.properties" instead of "messages.properties"

The problem was that Linux is case sensitive for file names that's why this snippet issued:

```
String resourcePath = className.replace('.', '/') + ".properties";
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
if (cl == null) {
  cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
}
URL r = cl.getResource(resourcePath);
if (r == null) {
  throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find the resource '"
      + resourcePath + " matching '" + className
      + "' did you remember to add it to your classpath?");
}
```

in com.google.gwt.i18n.tools.I18NSync:326 .

Comment: I have created http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8315 for this

Comment: How did you debug it? I have the same error however unfortunatly it is not the file name...

Comment: @Lonzak like the any Java process: you run it with in the debug mode: https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-remote-debugging#launch-command. Then using your fav. IDE listen for the debug port. F.e. for IDEA it is: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/attaching-to-local-process.html. Also (probably) GWT should be built with the debug info included.

Answer (score 0):

In our case maven somehow downloaded/created 0 kb files for the GWT dependencies in the local repository, including the one containing the i18N jars which then during executing time (logically) failed.

Additionally to increase the log level of the plugin the following configuration can be set:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <executions>
           ...
        </executions>
        <configuration>
                <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
                ...
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```